# AngularJS, UI Bootstrap DropDown Toggle, ng-click not firing if arguments are bound

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

Darndest problem, and I'm not sure where it lies. *(All variable names below insanitized to protect the guilty)*

If I have an ng-click on an ng-repeated item inside a [ui bootstrap dropdown toggle](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdownToggle) that uses a bound property, the ng-click doesn't fire.

Here I'm trying to pass the items Code property to a function.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" >Copy to <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="jigger in Thingies">
            <a ng-click="cloneItemTo('{{jigger.Code}}');">{{jigger.Name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If however I have an ng-click that uses a hardcoded value, the ng-click fires. Here I'm hardcoding the 'xxx' in place of where I'd like the items Code property used.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" >Copy to <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="jigger in Thingies">
            <a ng-click="cloneItemTo('xxx');">{{jigger.Name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the interesting bit of the controller

```
$scope.Thingies = [
   {"ID": 1,"Code": "itemone",    "Name": "Item One"}
  ,{"ID": 2,"Code": "itemtwo",    "Name": "Item Two"}
  ,{"ID": 3,"Code": "itemthree",  "Name": "Item Three"}
  ,{"ID": 5,"Code": "whereisfour","Name": "Item Five"}
];

$scope.cloningto = 'nowhere';

$scope.cloneItemTo = function(newType) {
    $scope.cloningto = newType;
}
```

I've stripped everything back to bare bones and created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ddq7qHT3JVmHf8gTa9DL?p=preview) and the problem still persists.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change line:

```
<a ng-click="cloneItemTo('{{jigger.Code}}');">{{jigger.Name}}</a>
```

to:

```
<a ng-click="cloneItemTo(jigger.Code);">{{jigger.Name}}</a></li>
```

Hope it will help,

Answer (score 2):

Replace this `cloneItemTo('{{jigger.Code}}');` with this `cloneItemTo(jigger.Code);` it worked for me in your Plunkr

Comment: Man, there's half a day I'll never get back. Thanks!